# handle excel file with java through javascript

Tags: java, javascript, web-services, excel

I am developing a Java webservice with an html/javascript/ajax client side.
Would there be any way that the user give a local excel file on input and to send it server side ?

I know that I can't get the path of the file because of security issues (C:/fakepath) and passing the content of the excel file through an ajax request doesn't seem to work.

Is there a solution to my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I did find a way around that problem with the new XMLHttpRequest version 2.

For more, see [**this**](http://www.technicaladvices.com/2011/12/10/ajax-file-upload-to-a-java-servlet-in-html5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can upload the file using the normal html upload mechanism:

Your HTML will look like this:

```
<html>
...
Select a file to upload: <br />
<form action="UploadServlet" method="post"
                    enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" size="200" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
...
</body>
</html>
```

And the corresponding jsp code to handle the upload. You can check out an example [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_file_uploading.htm).

Once you have the excel file on the server, you can process it however you want.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you know how to upload a file through the `<form>` and `<input>` tags in HTML, e.g.:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_script.php">
<input type="file" name="myfile" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

The trick to doing this asynchronously is to use an `<iframe>` and the `target` attribute in the `<form>` tag, e.g.:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_script.php" target="myiframe">
<input type="file" name="myfile" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>

<iframe name="myiframe"></iframe>
```

The frame can be made 0x0 pixels in size so the user doesn't know it's there. When the form is submitted the `iframe` loads the script page. JavaScript can be used to call back to the parent frame (i.e. the original window) to indicate whether the upload was a success or failure, etc..

Comment: Should there be a '/' at the end of the `input` tags? `<input ... />`?

Comment: @RyanAmos, that depends on the version of HTML (e.g. see http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4). But, it's nicer and more usual now, so I've added them.